# Is it true that $|x^a - y^a| \leq |(x-y)^a|$ on $[0,1]$, where $a\le 1$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

It looks to me like for a function $f(x) = x^a$ on the domain $[0,1]$ where $a \leq 1$, and $x,y$ are points in the domain,

$|x^a - y^a| \leq |(x-y)^a|$

I would like to use this in a proof and so if anyone could tell me if this is true or not and show why, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Suppose that $0 < y < x$. Then the inequality can be written $x^a \leqslant y^a + (x-y)^a$, or $(u+v)^a \leqslant u^a + v^a$ for $u, v > 0$. Have you an idea how to prove that?

Answer (score 3):

More generally, if $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ is an increasing function with decreasing derivative, then for $0\le x<y$
$$
|f(x)-f(y)| = \int_x^y f'(t)\,dt \le \int_a^b f'(t-x)\,dt = f(y-x)-f(0)
$$
Yours is a special case with $f(x)=x^a$, $0<a\le 1$.

---

One can also get this from concavity, which is what having decreasing derivative means.

Answer (score 2):

Check Lemma 2.3 of the following paper "[Non-Lipschitz continuous stabilizers for nonlinear systems with uncontrollable unstable linearization](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S016769110000089X)". It's not exactly the same inequality but using a similar reasoning it can also be shown that the power can also be taken less than 1.

[image]